# Knowing if the real derivative exists

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

The numerical derivative is valid only if the real derivative exists. Is it possible to know if the real derivative exists without using symbolic derivative, and using computer operations?

Comment: So you want a test for [Non Differentiable, But Continous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) functions, or are you talking about real vs. imaginary values? Please clarify.

Comment: @ja72:Test to know if it is possible to derive the function

Comment: Can you provide an example of a function you cannot derive? Even for the Weierstrass function you can derive it symbolically, but numerically it will not converge to a value regardless on how many terms are considered in the series.

Comment: Maybe the point is not to provide a function that can not be derived.The idea is not to use derivative symbolic. Can I use Weierstrass to know if the derivative exists using numerical calculations?

Comment: Then you just want a numeric derivative, but with an error estimation.

Comment: I want to know if that approximate numerical derivative calculation is valid at a point (ie there is a real derivative to the point)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)? It states that the slope (derivative) in an interval must equal to the average slope at some point. If you have values you will have an approxime derivative and it is all a matter of accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the comments above, I'm going to reformulate your question: given the ability to call a procedure

`float y = f(float x)`

(but not to look at the code for it!), you can estimate the derivative at a point $c$ by computing

```
h = .00001
d = (f(c + h) - f(c) ) / h
```

which will give you a numerical estimate. If you make $h$ smaller, the estimate will perhaps get better, or seem to converge on some value. You'd like to know whether the (mathematical) function implemented by the code in your procedure is in fact differentiable at $c$.

The answer is that you cannot know. Suppose that `EPS` is the smallest floating point number in your computer.  Consider these two functions

```
float y = f1(float x) :
if (abs(x) < EPS ) and (x is not 0) :
    y = 1
else
    y = 0


float y = f2(float x):
    y = 0
```

These return identical results for all values of $x$. But the first is an implementation of a function that's discontinuous, hence not differentiable, at 0, while the second implements a function that's certainly differentiable. But you cannot, using your computer, tell the difference.

I hope that this is of some help to you. The short form is "nothing you can do (easily) computationally is of much help is dealing with the intricacies of real analysis."